# Click Handler in markdown gatsbyjs

Tags: markdown, gatsby

is there any way to add a onClick handler in a markdown file. I create pages with "create pages" from markdown in gatsbyjs and they contain tables. every row has a "add" on the end that should open a small modal. And I would like to add an OnClick handeler to that "add". I tried all variations and it look something like this.

Markdown:

```
| f   | sef | wef  | df  |  <div onClick={this.handleClick}> add </div> |
```

and I added a handleClick function inside the template component for markdown

```
handleClick() {
        doSmth
      }
```

Or maybe another solution would be to add a react component instead of the div that contains add and the function?

Answer (score 1):

Other than what @MarceDev suggested, I think there's a few other ways you can go about this:

1. Use [remark custom components](https://using-remark.gatsbyjs.org/custom-components/) or [mdx](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx)
2. Add attribute like className to your generated markdown & target them on componentDidMount

---

I think in a React app, the first approach is a more 'correct' way of doing it, it takes a bit more to set up but in exchange you have a lot more flexibility.

Both links I share above have pretty detailed setup guide.

---

The second approach, in contrast, is often frowned upon because you'd be interacting directly with the dom. Personally, for something simple like a personal blog, and seeing that the markdown is generated outside of your own code, I wouldn't be too concerned.

For that, you could try this [remark plugin of mine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-remark-default-html-attrs) which gives attributes to generated markdown.

You could do something like:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
 +        {
 +          resolve:`gatsby-remark-default-html-attrs`,
 +          options: {
 +            "table": "table-class", // <table class="table-class">

              // custom attributes
 +            "table": {
 +              className: "table-class",
 +              style: "color: red;",
 +            },

              // select only the first table of a parent node
 +            "table:first-of-type {
 +              className: "table-class",
 +              ...
 +            }
 +          }
 +        }
        ],
      }
    }
```

Then target that class name on `componentDidMount`:

```
// template.js

/* ... */

  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof window == 'undefined') return;
    const $table = document.querySelector('.table-class')
    ...

  }

/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what your trying to achieve but you should probably be doing this the other way around. That is, if you want certain pages to have a table with JS you should be putting the table in a template. You can then call createPage with the template you made with your table in it. The docs walk you through the process pretty thoroughly. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/

Comment: if I put it in a template how can I fill the the table with data that is provided in the markdown? Is there anyway to fetch certain data from markdown that's not in the frontmatter. I have many markdown files and each file contains different data for the table